# ¿Utilizar modules CSS tras comparación?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Estoy intentando dar estilo a un componente de React en función al resultado de una comparación:

```
<div className={`${styles.titleContainer} ${(titleSelected === titleKey)?styles.titleSelected:''}`}
     onClick={() => handleTitleClick(titleKey)}></div>
```

sin embargo esto no funciona como debería y el resultado que me arroja el navegador es `undefined`.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta si es que la hay de realizar esta comparación?

Comment: ¿Dónde te aparece ese `undefined`? ¿Se genera algún div en el documento?

Comment: y `styles.titleSelected` si existe?